# Symfony2 twig form_widget customize html

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

How can I customize the the following code? I what to use checkboxes coming out of a Database.

This is my Form

```
$builder->add('entityname', 'entity', array(
             'class'    => 'MyBundle:applicant',
             'label'    => 'label',
             'property' => 'name',
             'expanded' => true,
             'required' => false,
             'multiple' => true,
             'attr' => array('class' => 'css-checkbox')
```

This is my Twig Layout

```
<div>
        <div>
            {% for entity in form %}
                {{ form_widget(entityname) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
</div>
```

This is what what I see in HTML:

```
<div id="name" class="css-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="name_1" name="name[entityname][]" value="1" />
<label for="name_1">AD DNS</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="name_2" name="name[entityname][]" value="2" />
<label for="name_2">Print</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="name_3" name="name[entityname][]" value="3" />
<label for="name_3">Citrix</label>
<div>
```

What I want to have is:

```
 <div id="name" class="css-checkbox">
<div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="name_1" name="name[entityname][]" value="1" />
    </div> 
    <div>
        <label for="name_1">AD DNS</label>
    </div> 
    <div>
       <input type="checkbox" id="name_2" name="name[entityname][]" value="2" />
    </div> 
    <div>
       <label for="name_2">Print</label>
    </div> 
 <div>
       <input type="checkbox" id="name_3" name="name[entityname][]" value="3" />
    </div> 
    <div>
       <label for="name_3">Citrix</label>
    </div>  
  <div>
```

How can I handle this with Twig?

Comment: If I understand right, you want to remove `Clients` from list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this to your twig template:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block checkbox_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
</div>
<div>
<label  for="{{ id }}">{{ label|trans }}</label>
</div>

{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to override form rendering:
1. override widget in the template
2. extends symfony .twig file woth the form elements definition

for more detilas see here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html